# Kotlin build failed in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

The error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':synclib:compileKotlin'.
> com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.LanguageFileType.<init>(Lcom/intellij/lang/Language;)V
```

The `build.gradle` file of the `synclib` module:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'


compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-jvm:2.2.3'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    compile project(':jamodel')

}
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

---

**How to fix or diagnose this?**

Comment: Did you try using Kotlin `1.0.4` instead of `1.0.0` ? Also, what's your gradle plugin version?

Comment: With `ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.4'` the error that happens is: `Error:Execution failed for task ':cloudtimemodel:compileKotlin'.
> Could not initialize class com.intellij.ide.highlighter.JavaFileType`

Comment: @Logain: which Gradle plugin do you mean? The one for Kotlin? If so, it is `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`

Comment: With `ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0'` and tried `1.0.4`

Comment: I was asking about the build tools too, i.e.: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'`

Comment: I have `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio build failed with Kotlin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228049/android-studio-build-failed-with-kotlin)

Comment: I hit this too - then I did a `gradlew --stacktrace build` in the Terminal to try to debug it - and the problem went away and the build completed.   Still don't know what the problem was.   The "configure Kotlin" step below indicated that Kotlin was configured.   The package was `kotlin-examples/gradle/android-dagger`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a working configuration. You can adapt it to your multi-project setup:

#### /build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.4'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    ext {
        androidBuildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"
        androidMinSdkVersion = 16
        androidTargetSdkVersion = 23
        androidCompileSdkVersion = 23
        androidApplicationId = "com.some.example"
        androidVersionCode = 1
        androidVersionName = "1.0"
        supportVersion = "24.0.0"
    }
}
```

#### /app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion parent.ext.androidCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion parent.ext.androidBuildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion parent.ext.androidMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion parent.ext.androidTargetSdkVersion
        versionCode parent.ext.androidVersionCode
        versionName parent.ext.androidVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check one-by-one, where we might differ.

Answer (score 1):

ensure all your apps and libs `build.gradle`'s `ext.kotlin_version` equal to your installed Kotlin version

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = PROP_KOTLIN_VERSION // 1.1.2-3 // this should equal to your installed Kotlin version
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions or check: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html

1. Choose **Help | Find Action** on the main menu or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
2. Search for this item:[image]
3. You would be prompted for `kotlin` version.

[image: *emphasized text*]
  Choose the latest available from the list of installed versions.

4. Now `build.gradle` file for the application should be updated.
5. The last thing to do is to `sync the project`. You can press '`Sync Now`' in a prompt or invoke an action **Sync Project with Gradle Files**.

Hope it will help