# Android Studio build failed with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

```
    :app:mergeDebugAssets
            :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
            :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug FAILED

            FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

            * What went wrong:
            Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
            > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK kotlin/internal/internal.kotlin_builtins
            File1: /Users/KD/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.0.4/172b43fbc03b521fed141484b212d6725fa671a9/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.0.4.jar
            File2: /Users/KD/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-runtime/1.0.4/8e25da5e31669f5acf514bdd99b94ff5c7003b3b/kotlin-runtime-1.0.4.jar
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app2par.ctime"
        minSdkVersion 16
//        minSdkVersion 21
//        targetSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled false
//        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g" // Use gig increments depending on needs
        incremental true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
//            testCoverageEnabled true
//            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = getCrashlyticsBetaMessage()
//            ext.betaDistributionGroupAliases = 'team'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
//    dataBinding {
//        enabled = true
// https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187443&q=attachments%3D0&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars
//    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':firebasesync')
    compile project(':liboid')
    compile project(':cloudtimemodel')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    //    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    //        transitive = true;
    //    }
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    // compile   'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.0.3.+'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.3.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.0.0' // play-services-plus:7.0.0 : office-mover
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0' // play-services-auth:8.3.0 : ShoppingList++

    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.0.0'
}
buildscript {
//    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0-rc-1036'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.4'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
//        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:grgit:1.1.0'
//        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
//        classpath 'org.kt3k.gradle.plugin:coveralls-gradle-plugin:2.5.0-x'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

**How to fix or diagnose this?**

Answer (score 2):

You should remove `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"` from your `dependencies` section and move it to `buildscript { dependencies { ... } }`.

Answer (score 2):

You did put `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"` in the wrong `build.gradle` file

You may use `kotlin` plugin's build-in converters to deal with this. According to `Kotlin Docs`:

> ### Configuring Kotlin in the project
>
> When adding a new Kotlin file, IntelliJ IDEA (and Android Studio)
>   automatically prompts us as to whether we'd like to configure the
>   Kotlin runtime for the project. However, currently, converting
>   existing Java file does not prompt this action. Therefore we have to
>   invoke it manually (via [Find Action](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigating-to-action.html)):
>
> [image: Config-Kotlin]
>
> We are then prompted for the version of Kotlin. Choose the latest
>   available from the list of installed versions.
>
> [image: Config-Kotlin-Details]
>
> After we configure Kotlin, build.gradle file for the application
>   should be updated. Now we can see that apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
>   and the dependencies were added.
>
> (For more details how to set up gradle for your project, please check
>   [Using Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html))
>
> The last thing to do is to sync the project. We can press `Sync Now`
>   in a prompt or invoke an action **Sync Project with Gradle Files**.
>
> [image: https://kotlinlang.org/assets/images/tutorials/kotlin-android/sync-project-with-gradle.png]
>
> From: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html

Check link above for more information.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply only one plugin, in your case `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` and only `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"` this dependency. it worked for me